Laravel on Windows Server (WSL/IIS) with TrendMicro/CrowdStrike Causes Slow Response Times
I'm running a Laravel application on a Windows Server environment using WSL and IIS, with TrendMicro or CrowdStrike as the antivirus/security client.
The issue I'm facing is unusual latency. When debugging, the boot time and response times are fine—around 50ms. However, the actual waiting time for requests in the browser is consistently more than 3 seconds.
I suspect the security client might be interfering, but I can't disable it entirely due to organisational policies.
Has anyone encountered this issue before? Are there any workarounds or configurations to improve response times while keeping the AV client enabled?
Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/defender-endpoint/configure-server-exclusions-microsoft-defender-antivirus#web-server-exclusions may help. Though the link contains different AV product,  I think IIS folder & process exclusion list should be similar
